# SAS_Specific Functions

Tags: sas

I have a question and want to ask question by using example. My data-set is:

```
 Group    Value 
  1       10
  1       8
  1       12
  2       13
  2       11
  2        7
```

I want to add two columns to this data-set. First column should consist of maximum value of second column by group. Second column should consist of minimum value of second column by group. So, the result should be look:

```
  Group    Value    Max    Min
  1         10     12      8
  1         8      12      8
  1         12     12      8
  2         13     13      7
  2         11     13      7
  2         7      13      7
```

12 - because there are 3 numbers (10,8,12) in group number 1 and 12 is maximum among these values.
13 - because there are 3 numbers (13,11,7) in group number 2 and 13 is maximum among these values.
8 - because there are 3 numbers (10,8,12) in group number 1 and 8 is minimum among these values.
7 - because there are 3 numbers (13,11,7) in group number 2 and 7 is minimum among these values.
I hope, i can explain it..
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? It what way was it not what you wanted?

Comment: If you're looking to do this in a `data step` then try sorting the data and using `first.` and `last.` logic. If you want to use a SAS procedure then look into `proc summary`. You can specify `min` and `max` in the `output` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
proc sql;
      select *,max(value) as max,min(value) as min from have group by group;
quit;
```